# STL vector.insert method expects _InputIterator as the arguments

Tags: c++, vector, stl, iterator

I have the following code:

```
typedef unsigned long int   U64;
std::vector<U64> vectorA;
std::vector<U64> vectorB;
vectorA.insert(vectorA.end(), vectorB.begin(), vectorB.end());
```

I'm getting compilation error at the last line, it could not find the method.

It expects following signature (code from *stl_vector.h*):

```
   template<typename _InputIterator,
           typename = std::_RequireInputIter<_InputIterator>>
    iterator
    insert(const_iterator __position, _InputIterator __first,
           _InputIterator __last)
```

How can I get the instance of the _InputIterator / _RequireInputIter for the instance of vector class? 
Can I do the same using different method?

I'm using gcc:

> gcc version 7.0.1 20170407 (experimental) [trunk revision 246759]
>   (Ubuntu 7-20170407-0ubuntu2)

and Ubuntu:

> NAME="Ubuntu" VERSION="17.04 (Zesty Zapus)"

edit:

I'm getting compilation error:

```
Invalid arguments ' Candidates are:
__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *,std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>>> insert(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const int
*,std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>>>, const int &)
__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *,std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>>> insert(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const int
*,std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>>>, int &&)
__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *,std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>>> insert(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const int
*,std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>>>, std::initializer_list<int>)
__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *,std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>>> insert
```

Comment: [mcve], please. This should work as written.

Comment: What is `U64` and what error do you get?

Comment: vector::begin() and end() are input iterators.

Comment: works fine with arbitrary type.. the header name doesn't look ith. is it  actual vanilla STL or its C++ standard vector? Your code perfectly compiles if U64 is  uint64 and  header   you use is <vector>

Comment: [Cannot duplicate](http://ideone.com/44RS7q)

Comment: Except for the typedef, what is in your code that is different than the [mcve] that I linked to?  Whatever it is, please put together your [mcve] that duplicates the issue.

Comment: The error message looks like you only provide two parameters.

Comment: I was generous enough to make  that example and provide in my answer. Compare it to your code. What is different? what are compiler's flags? what headers do you use? what possible perversions with `using namespace` there are?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I have the same compilation error for Your code. I will try to provide more information about the set up of my project/compiler.

Comment: @Dominik Kunicki just tell us what was wrong when you'll fix it.. for.. science. This is now  a matter of principle   :)

Comment: Sure, I will :) Regards.

Comment: I think the formatting got messed up a bit somewhere when you copied your compiler error; it doesn’t look quite right, is missing some of the information GCC usually provides, and it looks like it got cut off a bit at the end.

Comment: the error message is stll cut down.. if it end so abruptly.. only time i saw it happeng was when gcc was running out of memory (and parser gets screwed royally) due to circular inclusion of headers in program. that was quite a while ago and a  3.x version though.

Answer (score 3):

Ths code compiles and works without error. Tested with https://wandbox.org/

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

typedef unsigned long int   U64;
int main()
{
    std::vector<U64> vectorA = { 3, 4};
    std::vector<U64> vectorB = { 5, 7};
    vectorA.insert(vectorA.end(), vectorB.begin(), vectorB.end());

    for (const auto& i: vectorA)
      std::cout << i << ' ';
}
```

There is something you're not telling us.

Be aware that what is used here is NOT STL. STL is a legacy library that was created in 90s. What we are using now is standard C++ library which is based on STL and boost to extent. STL is still around for historical reasons. But STL doesn't  comply to C++ standard.  Something is wrong with include paths or with toolchain. It possible that you actually try to compile with vanilla STL headers, or some headers were mixed up with boost headers.

Comment: Swift's code also compiles and runs as expected with g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609

Comment: @systemcpro I think, wandbox runs on a debian, you can experiment with various compilers with that  thingy :p

Comment: Thanks for that. Just been playing with it on there too. So I have no idea. Need more info I methinks.

Comment: @systemcpro I just realized that I can do  `system("uname -a");` to check XD

Comment: This is not STL, but the majority of C++ programmers don’t know the difference and think the STL either is the name of the C++ standard library or a subset of it. The chance that actual STL headers are being mixed in is minimal, especially given the compiler error message indicating that this is libstdc++.

Comment: @Daniel H Yeah, I agree. but there are weird effects caused by header implementations able to pull ids from global namespace by `using` keyword. having headers from several sources and call  `using namespace std` or declaring ids that match  ids in standard library;  or something similar would cause compiler to do silly things.